# How to print listview in c

Tags: c, winapi, listview

I need to layout a listview content as a table to a printer using PrintDlg. Is there some simple way to do this using only WinAPI without any classes? Pure WinAPI and C.

Answer (score 0):

I won't guarantee it'll work, but you could try sending [WM_PRINTCLIENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the list view control.  You pass the printer DC as the wparam and set the appropriate flags in the lparam.  Not all controls implement WM_PRINTCLIENT, but it's worth a shot to see if it meets your needs.

If it doesn't work or if it doesn't meet your needs, you'll have to do a lot of work to print the contents yourself.  It's not particularly hard, but it would be a bit of code to measure everything in the printer context, select appropriate fonts and colors, format the table, etc.

Comment: Thank you for advice, the first thing works, but I get a very small layout in the corner of the page on a print , and I don't see any possibilities to resize it in WM_PRINTCLIENT documentation. You have said that there is some other way. Can you show some example code, please? Especially division on pages of listview that doesen't fit on a single page and how to queue all those pages to a print, and how to print in landscape mode. I have made some search and still don't get it.